# javascript classes call function

Tags: javascript

I am beginner in programming and I am trying the javascript classes, I want to call the **boardCastinit** function from the override function **onConnMessage**, but I am getting this error message, Please help in this issue.

> boReferenceError: boardCastInit is not defined

websocket.js

```
class websocket extends webSocketModel {

constructor() {
    let server = new Server();
    let mongodb = new mongoDB();
    super(server.server);
}




onConnMessage(message) {

    let clients = this.clients;
    boardCastInit(1);
}


 boardCastInit(data){
       console.log(data)
   }


}

module.exports = websocket;
```

websocketModel.js

```
const ws = require('websocket').server;

class webSocketModel {

constructor(httpServer) {
    if(!httpServer) throw 'Null Http Server';
    this.websocket = new ws({ httpServer: httpServer, autoAcceptConnections: false });
    this.websocket.on('request', this.onConnOpen.bind(this));
}


onConnOpen(request) {
    var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
    console.log('Connection Accepted');

    connection.on('message', this.onConnMessage);
    connection.on('close', this.onConnClose);
}

onConnMessage(message) {
    if (message.type === 'utf8') {
        console.log(message.utf8Data);
    } else if (message.type == 'binary') {
        console.log(message.binaryData.length + 'bytes');
    }
}

onConnClose(reasonCode, description) {
    console.log('Connection Closed');
}
}

module.exports = webSocketModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

just change `boardCastInit(1)` to `this.boardCastInit(1)`

```
onConnMessage(message) {

    let clients = this.clients;
    this.boardCastInit(1);
}
```

Comment: but it still return an error TypeError: this.boardCastInit is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling it from the class `this` reference:

```
class websocket extends webSocketModel {

   constructor() {
      let server = new Server();
      let mongodb = new mongoDB();
      super(server.server);
   }

   onConnMessage(message) {
      let clients = this.clients;
      this.boardCastInit(1);
   }


   boardCastInit(data){
      console.log(data)
   }

}

module.exports = websocket;
```

Comment: but it still return an error TypeError: this.boardCastInit is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this (should be this.boardCastInit(1)).

Comment: but it still return an error TypeError: this.boardCastInit is not a function

Comment: Not sure, but that's a proper way to call a method from inside a class. Which node version are you using? Also, what do you see if you do console.log(typeof this.boardCastInit)?

Comment: I change connection.on('message', this.onConnMessage);
to  connection.on('message', this.onConnMessage.bind(this));
and it works!

Comment: @Ekoar you missed the key part of code for this question so we couldn't help. glad to know it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a binding issue. Perhaps you want to use arrow function instead on your `onConnMessage` method:

```js
onConnMessage = (message) => {
    let clients = this.clients;
    this.boardCastInit(1);
}
```

This will ensure that `this` refers to the `websocket` class which has the `boardCastInit` method defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the `boardCastInit()` function inside the constructor like this.

```
constructor() {
    let server = new Server();
    let mongodb = new mongoDB();
    super(server.server);
    this.boardCastInit = this.boardCastInit.bind(this);
}
```

Then call it from the `this` reference.

```
onConnMessage(message) {
    let clients = this.clients;
    this.boardCastInit(1);
}
```